# Cache Size is about 6 MB on first launch

Tags: cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sencha-touch-2.2

I have a sencha touch based mobile app wrapped in phone-gap.  After building and installing i see that cache size in the application manager of android is ~6 M on first launch itself. Can someone tell me what could be the reason of this. Clearing this cache doesn't affect app functionality.

Thanks